# Pagination affects URLs in navigation in octobercms

Tags: octobercms

i made plugin names setup in this created three model and in pages printing data through builderlist but the problem is after clicking next or prev or number and then clicking on another link at menu then it replace only name instead of whole url...

**Agent.htm:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 tb-input-field-block">
                    {% set records = builderList.records %}
                    {% set displayColumn = builderList.displayColumn %}
                    {% set noRecordsMessage = builderList.noRecordsMessage %}
                    {% set detailsPage = builderList.detailsPage %}
                    {% set detailsKeyColumn = builderList.detailsKeyColumn %}
                    {% set detailsUrlParameter = builderList.detailsUrlParameter %}
                    {% for record in records %}
                    {# Use spaceless tag to remove spaces inside the A tag. #}
                    {% spaceless %}
                    {% for image in record.agentsteps %}
                    <a href="{{ image.path}}">
                        <img src="{{ image.thumb(auto,auto) }}" class="responsive">
                    </a>
                    <br>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <p>{{record.agent_content}}</p>
                    <br>
                    {% endspaceless %}
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="no-data">{{ noRecordsMessage }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if records.lastPage > 1 %}
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        {% if records.currentPage > 1 %}
                        <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (records.currentPage-1) }) }}" >&larr; Prev</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% for page in 1..records.lastPage %}
                        <li class="{{ records.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                            <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}" >{{ page }}</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% if records.lastPage > records.currentPage %}
                        <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (records.currentPage+1) }) }}" >Next &rarr;</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

**android.htm**

```
<div class="col-md-12 tb-input-field-block">


                {% set records = builderList.records %}
                {% set displayColumn = builderList.displayColumn %}
                {% set noRecordsMessage = builderList.noRecordsMessage %}
                {% set detailsPage = builderList.detailsPage %}
                {% set detailsKeyColumn = builderList.detailsKeyColumn %}
                {% set detailsUrlParameter = builderList.detailsUrlParameter %}

                    {% for record in records %}
                        {# Use spaceless tag to remove spaces inside the A tag. #}
                        {% spaceless %}
                        {% for image in record.androidimages %}

                        <a href="{{ image.path}}">
                            <img src="{{ image.thumb(auto,auto) }}" class="responsive">
                        </a>
                        <br>

                        {% endfor %}
                        {{record.android_content}}
                        <br>
                        {% endspaceless %}
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="no-data">{{ noRecordsMessage }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% if records.lastPage > 1 %}
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {% if records.currentPage > 1 %}
                    <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (records.currentPage-1) }) }}" >&larr; Prev</a></li>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% for page in 1..records.lastPage %}
                    <li class="{{ records.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                        <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}" >{{ page }}</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% if records.lastPage > records.currentPage %}
                    <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (records.currentPage+1) }) }}" >Next &rarr;</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}


            </div>
```

**menu:**

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><a class="white-font" href="{{'steps/agent'|page}}">Agent Installation</a></li>
                    <li><a class="white-font" href="{{'steps/android'|page}}">Android Steps</a></li>
                    <li><a class="white-font" href="{{'steps/ios'|page}}">IOS Steps</a></li>
                    <li><a class="white-font" href="{{'searchinput'|page}}">Support</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**menu:**
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSnE3.png)

**url after clicking on agent installation**
[url after clicking on agent installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j17x7.png)

**then clicking android steps then url is**[then clicking android steps then url is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAnxV.png)

**[backend view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s59pO.png)**

i just use builderlist and set 1 record per page but when i click on one link it gives 1 record per page and when i click on next link comes from pagination div iT makes url **like**:
 localhost/octoberCMS%20talltapps/install-master/steps/agent/2

and then i clicked on another link then it uses page num **like this**:
 localhost/octoberCMS%20talltapps/install-master/steps/android/2

but i want when i click on ANDROID SETUP the url must be **like** :

localhost/octoberCMS%20talltapps/install-master/steps/android

Comment: Please include code and output as content for your question, not are pictures. Please show us what you have attempted and explain why it is wrong.

Comment: i just use builderlist and set 1 record per page but when i click on one link it gives  1 record per page and when i click on next link comes from pagination div iT makes url like http://localhost/octoberCMS%20talltapps/install-master/steps/agent/2 and then i clicked on another link then it uses page num like this http://localhost/octoberCMS%20talltapps/install-master/steps/android/2 but i want when i click on ANDROID SETUP the url must be like http://localhost/octoberCMS%20talltapps/install-master/steps/android

Comment: Please include the **code** and **explanation** in the **question**, not in a comment.